# Запись данных из файла в базу данных.

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте, помогите с решением проблемы или посоветуйте в каком направлении идти, что почитать.
Вот есть файл (file.txt например).
В нем данные:

```
id:1
number:num1
text:text text
id:2
number:num2
text:text text text
```

То есть поля повторяются, только текст разный.

Необходимо записать эти данные в БД и в дальнейшем их обрабатывать как нужно.
Столбцы должны быть ID, Number, text.

Я вижу такое решение: необходимо создать эту БД. И записывать данные в этот файл.

Но как лучше всего считать этот файл и вставить данные в БД? Распознать что куда вставлять?

Comment: Возможно нужно создать массив и потом записать в БД?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.file.php прочитать файл в массив
- https://www.php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.foreach.php пройтись по массиву
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-database.html создать базу данных
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php подключиться к базе данных (посмотри в комментарии на той странице - много работающих примеров)
  `*` в частности надо https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php вставить запись в БД